# Classifier.predict In Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code in Python:

```
def plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier, resolution = 0.02):


    markers = ('s', 'x', 'o', '^','v')
    colors = ('red', 'blue', 'lightgreen', 'gray', 'cyan')
    cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])


    x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min() -1, X[:,0].max() + 1
    x2_min, x2_max = X[:, 1].min() -1, X[:,1].max() + 1
   xx1, xx2= np.meshgrid (np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution), np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
    Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
    Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha= 0.3, cmap = cmap)
    plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())
    plt.ylim(xx2.min(), xx2.max())


for idx, cl in enumerate (np.unique(y)):
    plt.scatter (x=X[y == cl, 0], y= X[y == cl, 1], alpha=0.8, c=colors[idx], marker= markers [idx], label = cl, edgecolor = 'black')
```

Where `X` is a 100x2 vector with normal data (sepal and petla length for 2 kinds of flowers) , `y` is a  100x1 vector with only -1 and 1 values (class label vector) and `Classifier = Perceptron` . I don't know why I need to calculate the transpose

```
Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
```

What does

```
classifier.predict
```

and

```
x=X[y == cl, 0], y= X[y == cl, 1]
```

in

```
plt.scatter (x=X[y == cl, 0], y= X[y == cl, 1], alpha=0.8, c=colors[idx], marker= markers [idx], label = cl, edgecolor = 'black')
```

do?

I previously load a dataframe, define my predict method, define `X` and `y`

```
def predict(self,X):
    '''Return class label after unit step'''
    return np.where(self.net_input(X) >= 0.0, 1, -1)
```

And my `class = Perceptron` contains the `w_` (weights) that are adjusted when iterating. Sorry if my english is not perfect

```
y = df.iloc[0:100 , 4] .values
y= np.where (y == 'Iris-setosa', -1, 1)

X= df.iloc[0:100, [0,2]].values
```

Comment: Can you give us some more detail about the context? I.e.: what you are trying to classify? What are the parameters `X` and `y` in the function call? What do they contain (i.e.: `X` contains data and `y` the class labels)?

Comment: I put more more information now. Tell me if it's not enough

Comment: Can you post enough code to reproduce your results? this should include a random `X` and `y` array, `colors`, and `markers`.

Comment: I put more information. For `colors` and `markers` they were defined in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this down, first:

```
np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()])
```

`.ravel()` flattens the `xx1` and `xx2` arrays. `xx1` and `xx2` are just coordinates (for feature1 and feature2 respectively) arranged in a grid pattern. Idea is that `xx1` and `xx2` are coordinates at every `resolution` interval in the range of the feature-set. With enough of these coordinates, you can effectively know what regions are classified as what label by your classifier.

```
np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T
```

The reason you need the transpose is because the `.predict()` method expects as input an array of size `[n_samples, n_features]`. The result of the ravelled array will be of size `[n_features, n_samples]`, which is why we need to transpose.

```
classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T
```

This makes the predictions for each of the meshgrid points (which is then used to make a mask over the plot to show which regions are classified as what label by the classifier).

```
plt.scatter (x=X[y == cl, 0], y= X[y == cl, 1], alpha=0.8, c=colors[idx], marker= markers [idx], label = cl, edgecolor = 'black')
```

Here, we plot our samples. We want to plot each class of samples seperately (in order to have them be different colors), so `x=X[y == cl, 0]` and `y= X[y == cl, 1]` are saying only plot the point at points where the label is equal to the current one we are inspecting (ie `cl`). `cl` will just be an iteration of all the unique possible labels.

It's easier to understand once you see what the result looks like (here's an example using a `make_blobs` dataset and an `MLPClassifier`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

def plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier, resolution = 0.02):
    markers = ('s', 'x', 'o', '^','v')
    colors = ('red', 'blue', 'lightgreen', 'gray', 'cyan')
    cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])

    x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min() -1, X[:,0].max() + 1
    x2_min, x2_max = X[:, 1].min() -1, X[:,1].max() + 1
    xx1, xx2= np.meshgrid (np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution), np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
    Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
    Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha= 0.3, cmap = cmap)
    plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())
    plt.ylim(xx2.min(), xx2.max())

colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
X, y = make_blobs(n_features=2, centers=3)

for idx, cl in enumerate (np.unique(y)):
    plt.scatter (x=X[y == cl, 0], y= X[y == cl, 1], alpha=0.8, c=colors[idx], label = cl, edgecolor = 'black')

classifier = MLPClassifier()
classifier.fit(X, y)

plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier, resolution = 0.02)
```

You get:
[image]

Comment: Thanks you, you explain very well. One least question: Why I must do `Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)` ? I think it is to recover the shape that the vector had before transposing it

Comment: Its to recover the shape of the predictions to the shape of the meshgrid, since that's what `plt.contourf` accepts. Before the reshape, Z is a one dimensional vector.